# How to limit how far someone can pan on my map

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic3, ionic-native

Using Ionic 3 and the ionic-native google maps (and cordova) plugins, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to limit how far someone can pan.

I found the [latLngBounds class](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/tree/master/documents/latlngbounds), but 1) It says how to create it but not how to implement it, and 2) I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question for those who come across this same question later on.  Within your map preferences, there's an option for `gestureBounds` which takes the lat/lng of the 4 corners.

See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/tree/master/documents/googlemapprefereceoptions